# How to correctly pass ssh key file from Jenkins credentials variable into to docker build command?

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, credentials, jenkins-docker

This question is a follow up to this question
[How to pass jenkins credentials into docker build command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193016/how-to-pass-jenkins-credentials-into-docker-build-command)

I am getting the ssh key file from jenkins credential store in my groovy pipeline and
passing it into docker build command via --build-arg so that I can checkout and build artifacts from the private git repos from within my docker container

credentials store id : cicd-user, which works for checking out my private works as expected from my groovy Jenkinsfile

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'cicd-user', url:'ssh://git@bitbucket.myorg.co:7999/A/software.git']]
```

I access it and try to pass the same to docker build command:

```
  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'cicd-user', keyFileVariable: 'FILE')]) { 
           sh "cd ${WORKSPACE} && docker build -t ${some-name} --build-arg USERNAME=cicd-user --build-arg  PRIV_KEY_FILE=\$FILE --network=host -f software/tools/jenkins/${some-name}/Dockerfile ."
        }
```

in Dockerfile I do

```
RUN echo "$PRIV_KEY_FILE" > /home/"$USERNAME"/.ssh/id_rsa && \
 chmod 700 /home/"$USERNAME"/.ssh/id_rsa
```

RUN echo "Host bitbucket.myorg.co\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config

But I am seeing the following issue

> "Load key "/home/cicd-user/.ssh/id_rsa" :(invalid format)
> "git@Bitbucket.mycomp.co:Permission denied( Public key)
> "fatal: could not read from remote repository"

In the past I have passed the ssh priv key as --build-arg from outside by cat'ing like below

--build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"

Should I do something similar

--build-arg PRIV_KEY_FILE="$(cat $FILE)"

Any idea on what might be going wrong or where I should be looking for debugging this correctly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue yesterday and I think I've come up with a workable solution.

Here are the basic steps I took - using the [sshagent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) to manage the sshagent within the Jenkins job.  You could probably use withCredentials as well, though that's not what I ended up finding success with.

The ssagent (or alternatively the key) can be made available to specific build steps using the `docker build` commands --ssh flag.  [(Feature reference)](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) It's important to note that for this to work (at the current time) you need to set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1. If you forget to do this, then it seems like it ignores this configuration and the ssh connection will fail. Once that's set, the sshagent

Cut down look at the pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        // ...
    }
    environment {
        // Necessary to enable Docker buildkit features such as --ssh
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT = "1"
    }
    stages {
        // other stages

        stage('Docker Build') {
            steps {
                // Start ssh agent and add the private key(s) that will be needed in docker build
                sshagent(['credentials-id-of-private-key']) {
                    // Make the default ssh agent (the one configured above) accessible in the build
                    sh 'docker build --ssh default .'
                }
            }
        // other stages
        }
    }
}
```

In the Dockerfile it's necessary to explicitly give lines that need it access to the ssh agent.  This can be done by including `mount=type=ssh` in the relevant RUN command.

For me, this looked roughly like this:

```
FROM node:14
# Retrieve bitbucket host key
RUN mkdir -p -m -0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
...
# Mount ssh agent for install
RUN --mount=type=ssh npm i
...
```

With this configuration, the npm install was able to install a private git repo stored on Bitbucket by utilizing the SSH private key within docker build via sshagent.

Answer (score 1):

After spending one week I found some how reasonable way to do.
just add

RUN git config --global url."https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com"

into your docker file and it will install if it needs to install private packages as well.

add pass your GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN (you can have it in your github settings account with setting proper permissions) where you are building your image. Like
docker build --build-arg GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=yourtoken -t imageNameAndTag .